# run glDispatchCompute in a loop

Tags: glsl, compute-shader

Can i run this code in a loop without reading results from SSBO? And only read SSBO results after 100 iterations.

```
for (int i=0; i <100; i++){
 glDispatchCompute(1, 200, 1);    
 glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);//i understand this needed to ensure 
                 //it is done running the glsl code in GPU from previous iteration
}
```

Also will glsl code executed e.g. second time within the loop(i==1) see results of first glsl execution in SSBO (i==0)?

Finally do i really need  glMemoryBarrier call in the loop or it can be outside the loop? I am concerned that GPU code will not see changes done by first iteration in SSBO when executed second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, you can run your shader multiple times without reading the contents of the buffer you are writting to and read them at the end (this is a very common practice on iterative GPU sorting algorithms)

2) If you are reading/writting to the same buffer, yes, they will be visible

3) Yes, you need a barrier, otherwise the compute shader dipatch will be launched without waiting for the previous to finish, which will lead to wrong results (as you are concerned), if not crashes. However, the barrier type will depend on what you are doing within your shader. Here is a full list of barriers

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMemoryBarrier.xhtml

Most probably, if you are focusing on reading/writing to a SSBO, you should use the barrier `GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT`, but if you are not sure, you can just use `GL_ALL_BARRIER_BITS`.